# Webpage menu hover effect with object that follows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to make a menu bar on a website using a set of anchor elements. So far everything is exactly working as planned.

Now i want an image to follow the users selection. So the image is at the current active menu item, but when the user hovers their mouse to another menu item, the image will follow to that particular item.

I tried searching the web for it but i get a lot of simple hover effects, not the one I want. So maybe one of you can help me with an example or give me a push in the right direction.

My menu is made like this

```
<nav id="page-nav">
    <a href="#">item #1</a>
    <a href="#">item #2</a>
    <a href="#">item #3</a>
    <!-- etcetera -->
</nav>
```

I'm now using CSS to make it into a menu bar.

```
a {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 156px;
        height: 37px;

        top: -1px;

        text-align: center;
        line-height: 41px !important;

        color: #c3c3c3;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px black;
        text-transform: uppercase;

        font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Calibri", sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;

    }
```

I want the image to follow the users action. If i use the image as a background on the buttons, it is not possible to make it slide from one item to another...

Thanks!

Comment: Show us some code. You probably just need to override that CSS property for the `:hover` state.

Comment: This is a very open ended question.  We don't know what you didn't like about the hovers so how could we help you?

Comment: More details needed. For instance, the "image to follow the users selection", do you mean a custom mouse cursor, an icon next to the menu item that starts following the mouse as long as you hover, or something else?

Comment: Excuse me for the incomplete question. I added code examples from my current code. The hover examples I found were regular "different color" "different formatting" css hover effects. I'm really looking for an image to slide along the menu bar horizontally depending on the user's current hovered menu item. Hope this is more clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/mkdvg)

I made a little nub, but you can give it a background image, or replace it with an image, or whatever.  It uses CSS transitions, so it will teleport on oldish browsers.

```
.blip {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(100, 100, 255, .4);
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  top: -10px;;
  left: -100px;
  -webkit-transition: left .5s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: left .5s ease-in-out;
          transition: left .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

If you don't want to use CSS transitions, replace the `.css` with `.animate`.

```
var $blip = $('.blip');

$('#page-nav>a').on('mouseover', function(){
  $blip.css({
    left: $(this).offset().left 
        - $(this).parent().offset().left 
        + $(this).width() / 2 
        - 20 // 20 is one half of .blip's width
  });
});

$('#page-nav').on('mouseout', function(){
  $('.blip').css({left: -100});
});
```